# How to use the Comparison Test to investigate the convergence of $\sum (\ln n)/n^\alpha$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, induction

Let $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}, \alpha\in\Bbb{R}$$

I need to investigate the convergence of this series.

I've read that since the series is positive for all $n$ then it converges if and only if $\alpha > 1$, but isn't it true only for a p-series ($\sum \frac{1}{n^p})$?

For $\alpha \le 1$ the auther mention we can use this equality:
$$\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}. \forall n\in\Bbb{N}$$

And then compare it to the harmonic series and we're done. But this claim is non-trivial. I wish to know how to prove it before using it. I tried to do so by induction but got stuck somewhere.

I'd be glad if you could help me understand it properly.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it. For $\alpha\le 1$ the inequality you posted  is trivial and the proof that series are not converge is finished.

Comment: You're absolutly right. I should get some sleep :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If $\alpha\le1$ then
  $$\frac1n\le\frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha},\quad n\ge3$$
  so by comparison with the harmonic series the given series is divergent.
- If $\alpha>1$ then let $1<\alpha'<\alpha$ so
  $$\frac{\ln n}{n^\alpha}\le\frac1{n^{\alpha'}},\;\text{for}\; n \;\text{sufficently large}$$
  so the given series is convergent by comparison with a convergent Riemann series.

Comment: You have to prove that such $\alpha^\prime > 1 $ exists.

Comment: What do you mean and what I should prove? Isn't it trivial?

Comment: Sorry, for me  it is not. I only have condition $\alpha-\alpha^\prime \ge \log(\log(n))/\log(n)$. Could you proceed?

Comment: Yes it seems trivial for me now :).

Comment: Pick any $1<\alpha'<\alpha$  and since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{\alpha-\alpha'}}=0$$
then there's $n_0$ such that
$$\frac{\ln n}{n^{\alpha-\alpha'}}\le 1,\quad \forall n\ge n_0$$
and this inequality gives the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Use the properties $\varepsilon^{-1}\log(n^{\varepsilon})=\log(n)$ and $\log(n)<n$ to get an upper bound in a simpler (power) form.