# For which $a\in\mathbb{R}$ does $\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\ln(k)}{k^a}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

We can use:

- $\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k^s}$ converges if and only if $s>1$;
- $\lim_{k→\infty} \frac{\ln(k)}{k^t}=0$ for $t>0$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Mark We have proven that for $a\leq 1$ the series is divergent. Furthermore we tried using a few lemmas. Like if $\lim_{k\to\infty} |\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}|<1$ then the series $\sum a_k$ is convergent. And if $|a_k|\leq C t_k$, then the series $\sum a_k$ converges when the series $\sum t_k$ converges.

Comment: A similar question can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894153/how-to-use-the-comparison-test-to-investigate-the-convergence-of-sum-ln-n-n.

Comment: Let $a > 1$.  Then we can write $a = 1 + 2\delta$ and $\ln(k)/k^a = \ln(k)/k^\delta \cdot 1 /k^{1+\delta}$.  As $k \to \infty$ the first term has limit zero (given).  Thus, for all large enough $k$, $\ln(k)/k^a < \tfrac{1}{2} 1/k^{1+\delta}$.  The sum of these terms converges and therefore by the comparison test the series $\sum\ln(k)/k^a$ also converges.  You say you have already shown divergence when $a \leqslant 1$.

Comment: @WADon Could you elaborate on the fact that $\ln(k)/k^a < \frac{1}{2} 1/k^{1+\delta}$? It seems to me that for a large enough $k$, the $1/k^{1+\delta}$ will also be zero.

Comment: Because $\ln(k)/k^\delta \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, eventually it will become less than $1/2$.  Then, 
$$\frac{\ln(k)}{k^a} = \frac{\ln(k)}{k^\delta} \cdot \frac{1}{k^{1+\delta}} \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{k^{1+\delta}}.$$  
The rightmost terms have finite sum, so the comparison test may be used.  Hope that helps.